# Editing IronPython during runtime?

Tags: ironpython

I installed IronPython and wrote up a winform app. Its [this but modified](http://www.theswamp.org/index.php?topic=12090.0;wap2) to use a MessageBox. I want to change the text i display when clicked. Changing it and hitting save does not update the script. I paused it, set a breakpoints, done a few things and had no luck.

How do i edit text during runtime? there doesnt appear to be a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure IronPython doesn't support edit & continue. It's extremely difficult to get working correctly (it isn't even supported for x64 in Visual Studio), so it's unlikely it will be available anytime soon.

Comment: That kind of sucks as edit & continue works for C#. and the fact this is dynamic.

Comment: I was sort of surprised to discover this too. I suppose they could `reload()` the module you just modified, but then again, I'm not familiar with the intricacies of the DLR when it comes to changing code in memory...

Comment: I'm sure it would be possible - but Visual C# has dozens of full time staff, and IronPython is built by volunteers. It's a matter of balancing resources and priorities.